# Calculating the probability of a sequence having $n$ terms in a certain set.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $\Delta$ be  the interval $[0,1]$, then we can consider the probability space $(\Delta , \mathcal{B}(\Delta),m)$, where $\mathcal{B}(\Delta)$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and $m$ is the Lebesgue measure.

Then we can endow the space $\Delta^{\mathbb{N}}:= \{ (\omega_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}};\  \omega_n \in \Delta, \ \forall \ n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ with the $\sigma$-algebr $\mathcal{B}(\Delta^{\mathbb{N}})$ (Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\Delta^{\mathbb{N}}$ induced by the  product topology) and the probability measuare $m^{\mathbb{N}}$ in the measurable space$(\Delta^{\mathbb{N}},\mathcal{B}(\Delta^{\mathbb{N}}))$, such that

$$m^{\mathbb{N}} \left(A_1\times A_2\times \ldots \times A_n \times \prod_{i=n+1}^{\infty} \Delta\right)=m(A_1) \cdot \ldots\cdot m(A_n). $$

Now, consider the Bernoulli shift map 
\begin{align*}
\sigma: \Delta^{\mathbb{N}}&\to\Delta^\mathbb{N}\\
(\omega_n)_{n}&\to (\omega_{n+1})_n.
\end{align*}

It is well known that the measure $m^{\mathbb{N}}$ on $(\Delta^{N}, \mathcal{B}(\Delta^{\mathbb{N}}))$ is invariant under $\sigma$. Moreover the pair $(\sigma,m^{\mathbb{N}})$ is ergodic. So, Birkhoff's theorem says that for any cilinder
$$\Lambda = A_1\times A_2\times \ldots \times A_n \times \prod_{i=n+1}^{\infty} \Delta, $$
where all $A_i$'s are open subsets of $\Delta$,
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \chi_{\Lambda}(\sigma^{i}( (\omega_j)_j)) = m^{\mathbb{N}}(\Lambda),\ \text{$m^{\mathbb{N}}$- a.s.} $$

> **My Question:** Birkhoff's theorem says that for almost every $(\omega_n)_n\in \mathbb{\Delta^{\mathbb{N}}}$, there exists $i = i((\omega_n)_n)\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $(\omega_{i+1},...,\omega_{i+n})\in A_1 \times ...\times A_n$. Is it possible calculate (or estimate) the following probability
>   $$P_m(\Lambda) := m^{\mathbb{N}}\left(\left\{((\omega_n)_{n};\ \exists\ i \in \{0,...,m\}\ \text{such that }\sigma^{i}(\omega) \in \Lambda\right\}\right)\ ? $$
>   Moreover, given $\varepsilon>0$, are there $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$, such that
>   $$1- P_n(\Lambda) < \varepsilon, \forall n > n_0  ? $$

Comment: isn't this just very basic probability, having nothing to do with ergodic theory? you can just calculate $m^{\mathbb{N}}(\{(\omega_n)_n : \sigma^i(\omega) \not \in \Lambda \text{  } \forall i \in \{0,\dots,m\})$ directly.

Comment: Not sure how I do this. At least in my point of view, it is a complicated task. Nevertheless, I agree with you that maybe there is no need to use ergodic theory.